# equivalent to @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop") on quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus

I would like to know if there is some equivalent annotation on Quarkus for

> @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")

I am working with a third-party lib which has a class that is final, thus I cannot extends it to implement @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy.
The solution on Spring would be very simple, I would just need to initialize its bean with those two arguments on the annotation; However, I could not find something similar to that on Quarkus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution from CDI, which apparently works in Quarkus (see [Quarkus CDI Reference/Supported features](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#supported_features)), is to use producers and disposers. So, in a class:

```java
@ApplicationScoped // might not be needed - TBD
public class ThirdPartyBeanManager {
    @Produces @ApplicationScoped // use the appropriate scope
    public ThirdPartyBean getThirdPartyBean() {
        ThirdPartyBean thirdPartyBean = new ThirdPartyBean();
        // ***HERE IS THE MANUAL @PostConstruct/initMethod CALL***
        thirdPartyBean.start();
        return thirdPartyBean;
    }

    // ***THIS IS THE EQUIVALENT OF @PreDestroy/destroyMethod***
    public void dispose(@Disposes ThirdPartyBean thirdPartyBean) {
        thirdPartyBean.stop();
    }
}
```

There may be some details that need ironing out (e.g. the "manager" does not have to be a full CDI bean, nor does it need to keep a reference to the produced bean, I think), but this is the general concept.

Another idea that builds on this concept, would be to wrap the third party dependency in an API of your own. Your API/bean will be using the third party internally and will forward its own `@PostConstruct`/`@PreDestroy` calls to the third party. The disadvantage is more code; the advantage is that now your application is decoupled from the 3rd party, the most immediate consequence of that being you can now mock that dependency in tests.

Comment: Nice, this seems to do the work =). Thank you so much